# How i can i run laravel dusk test cases on front-end?

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

My current situation is that I have a button when I click on that a single particular test case that was created using Laravel dusk should run and its log should display in a browser like Passed/Failed how much time taken etc.

I tried **exec()** and **shell_exec()** to execute a dusk command but it shows me the error 'Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\Internal\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for HTTP POST to /session/bf290732b699eca73947777aa65c56f0/url with params: {"url":"http://localhost:8000/enterprise/login"}
' error.

I had also tried **Artisan::call('dusk')** but it says 'dusk command not found'.

Laravel dusk library is installed in my local system and when I execute this command on the command prompt it works as expected but didn't work through PHP code.

Is there any way to achieve my desired solution??

Any help will be appreciated...